# After running react-native run-android: Resolving dependencies takes forever to finish

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, dependencies

After running command `npx react-native run-android`, progress will be stuck at `100% CONFIGURING`.

It says `Resolve dependencies of:` associated with the package/dependency.

Here's an image:
[loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7FgM.png)

Comment: Legend says, it still running..

Comment: This seems more like an issue you should bring up to the package maintainers, rather than an appropriate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @EldarB. Thanks, but was just wondering that any of you guys have encountered the same issue.